# Iterate over struct and perform database queries

Tags: go, iteration

So I'm new to go and I come from a javascript/node background and for practice, I've been rewriting some of my javascript code into go.

I have a situation where I have an struct (in node it was my object) and I need to iterate over it and perform two database queries. I have something that works but it seems costly and repetitive.

**Struct:**

```
type SiteUsers struct {
    Active struct {
        Moderators []string `json:"moderators"`
        Admins     []string `json:"admins"`
        Regulars   []string `json:"regulars"`
    } `json:"active"`
}
```

Then in the function where I handle an api request that returns JSON binded to this struct I use a for range loop for each role under active. For each one I perform the same first query and then a second one that is specific to each one.

```
v := getSiteUsers(&usrs, website)

for _, moderators := range v.Active.Moderators {
    // Insert into user table
    // Insert into user table with role of moderator
}

for _, admins := range v.Active.Admins {
    // Insert into user table
    // Insert into user table with role of admin
}

for _, regulars := range v.Active.Regulars {
    // Insert into user table
    // Insert into user table with role of regular
}
```

This method will work but it doesn't feel completely right and I would love to get some input from people experienced with go.

Comment: Declare `Admins` and `Regulars` as a concrete type so you can avoid type assertions when inserting into the tables.

Comment: What about that method doesn't feel right to you? Are you thinking you could do this without having three separate loops? Also, why are `Admins` and `Regulars` slices of empty interface instead of slices of some type?

Comment: You can use [GORM](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0grWu_7_XAhUCtxQKHUhNCEgQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fjinzhu%2Fgorm&usg=AOvVaw2jjszk_MAcWnVY3dnZYIFW) ORM, It supports structs for models and you can insert whole object to the database.

Comment: Apart from the suggestion by @CeriseLimón, you could have CRUD methods for interaction with the database which could make it look cleaner.

Comment: @AndySchweig It just feels taxing I guess. I would avoid this method completely in javascript because of speed. Also I believe that's a mistake I will fix it right away.

Comment: @Ravi I'm not sure if I understood you correctly or not but I do have CRUD type methods for inserting users with roles and whatnot (unless that's not what you meant), it's just the three separate loops that doesn't feel right

Comment: @AndySchweig As an example, in javascript I would use an object loop and the role would be the key and the name would be the value and it's very compact and I only have to use the Insert queries once each (in code).

Comment: If the role is the only thing that's different for the three lists of users, you could write a function that takes  a slice of strings and the role as arguments and call that for each list. That seems pretty obvious, though, so maybe it's more complicated than that...?

Comment: @AndySchweig Could you mock up a simple function like that for me, or point me in the right direction to do something similar. Structs and slices are new to me so any help is appreciated. I unfortunately don't learn well from the documentation, although they did a good job writing the docs I learn best from relevant examples.

Comment: @AndySchweig has shown the way for what I meant, for insert (Create) - one method to insert. Same for other CRUD operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this be better?

```
v := getSiteUsers(&usrs, website)

insertUsers := func(users []string, role roleType) {
    for _, user := range users {
        // Insert into user table
        // Insert into user table with given role
    }
}

insertUsers(v.Active.Moderators, moderatorRole)
insertUsers(v.Active.Admins, adminRole)
insertUsers(v.Active.Regulars, regularRole)
```